# Trying to create a HOG implementation for detecting people

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I would like to create results similar to the video found [at this link](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/pubs/2005/DT05/demo.mpeg).  I tried the Object Detection and Localization toolkit made for the work done by Dalal and Triggs [found here](http://pascal.inrialpes.fr/soft/olt/), and I tried trainHOG(https://github.com/DaHoC/trainHOG), a program that uses OpenCV that can be trained to detect people.

For the ODL toolkit, I had problems compiling because its requirements are now dated.  The Ubuntu packages that provide the requirements for ODL (ImLib, Boost, and Blitz)  are not compatible with the versions of the packages required by ODL. I actually went through a lot of effort building older versions of the required packages but hit a dead end of an error saying:
 error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::program_options::validation_error::validation_error(std::basic_string)’                          + argument.desc.find(*ai, false).format_name());

For trainHOG I was able to detect people but only if they were very small in the image. I also got a lot of false positives.  I trained it with 1133 positive images and ~8500 negative image, all of which were 64x128 in size.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV has a API for  [HOG Descriptor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.htm)  which you can use easily.

However, HOG is very very simple to implement and it should take whole deal of time for you to implement. You can refer to [this tutorial](http://chrisjmccormick.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/hog-person-detector-tutorial/) which I found to be very helpful when for understanding HOG.

If you still find problem than let me know so I can help you code it.

Comment: The link to the HOG Descriptor API doesn't work.  Also, I'd like to do this without gpu acceleration.  Thanks for helping.